# How many attributes can I add to the SphinxSearch index?

Tags: mysql, sphinx

How many attributes can I add to the SphinxSearch index? Is there any restrictions? I haven't found any information in the docs. I have 111 columns in the MySQL table and I want to do faceted search on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no restriction for attributes. Fulltext fields are limited to 256.